# How to use extension methods as arguments in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I would like to implement a DSL similar to what they can do with builders in Kotlin: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html

The idea is use extension methods as function arguments, so that you can use methods from the class being extended within the closure you give a argument. Essentially allowing you to inject methods and variables into the scope of the closure.

It seems to be *almost* possible in Swift, but maybe I am missing something. The following code works, right until I try to call `head()` within the closure:

```
// Class with method to be available within closure
class HTML {  
    func head() {  
        print("head")  
    }  
}  

// Create a type with same signature as an extension method  
typealias ext_method = HTML -> () -> ()  

func html(op: ext_method) {  
    let html = HTML()  
    op(html)() // call the extension method
}  

html {  
    head() // ! Use of unresolved identifier 'head'  
}
```

Have anyone had any luck doing something similar, or have an idea to how it would be possible?

Comment: You might mention that this is also posted in the Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20481.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but what is a *DSL*  in this context?

Comment: @MartinR domain-specific language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language

Comment: @ast What you need here is to "inject" the object `html` in the scope, so it would be accessed via `self` keyword. That haw it is done in Kotlin: `html.op()`. /reference/lambdas.html#extension-function-expressions AFAIK, it is a +unique+ feature of Kotlin, that even Scala doesn't have.

Comment: @ast Try to implement something simular to Kotlin's `with` function: `inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, f: T.() -> R): R`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is what you are looking for, but

```
html {
    $0.head  
}
```

would compile and seems to produce the expected output.

The closure takes a single parameter (here using the shorthand
parameter name `$0`) which is an instance of `HTML`. It returns
the instance method `$0.head` as a function of type `() -> ()`.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to avoid the initial $0. One of the key features of extension methods is that they can directly access method in the class they extend, but that ability seem to get lost when used as closures.

Comment: @ast: The closure is not in the scope of the HTML class or extension declaration, so *I* don't see how to achieve that. Perhaps someone else does ...